How can I blue/green update an AWS RDS clone to match its source?
I created an AWS RDS clone a week ago from my production database cluster. I would like to throw away everything I've done on the clone and update its contents to match the current contents of the production cluster.
My naive approach would be to delete the clone and re-create it. However, this takes a long time during which the clone is inaccessible.
I would much rather try to take advantage of the blue/green deployment functionality of RDS, but I can't see a fast path toward making that work. I could start a blue/green deployment on the clone then perform an explicit copy of all the contents of the production cluster to the green clone, but that could take hours, and I suspect it would entirely break the copy-on-write benefits of the clone.
Is there any way to get blue/green functionality with a new clone instead, switching from the outdated clone to a fresh clone in about the same amount of time as the sum of creating a clone and doing a blue/green swap?
